# PayPal Adaptive Account Creation Using Light Box

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Adaptive Accounts to let my site users create their accounts on PayPal. I want to use light box on top of my web site's page, so that users do not feel they are going outside of my web site, i.e. I am not redirecting to PayPal site for account creation.

For this purpose, I use **PayPal Adaptive Accounts** "Create Account" Classic API operation.

I am getting a URL from "Create Account" operation, which I want to open in a light box.

Here, I have certain questions:

1. Does any body has done this before and if kind enough provide code sample for this?
2. After the user creates his/her account on PayPal page displayed inside a light box on my site, how my page will know if the user successfully created his/her account and show a confirmation message that his account in PayPal has been successfully created.
3. Does PayPal provide any JavaScript for this purpose or I should create my JavaScript code of my own? Can dg.js be used? I am confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, lightbox feature is not supported due to security concerns. However, paypal supports minibrowser. As far as knowing when somebody is done setting up their account, with the minibrowser flow they would get an IPN when the password is created. SDKs have sample code for this.

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/